# Chrome - Detect When Browser Exits

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am wondering if it is possible to detect whether the user exits the Chrome browser?

EDIT - Sorry, I wasn't being very clear so I'll explain my situation. I am storing some variables in the browser's localstorage. When the user closes the browser, I want to delete some of these variables.

Comment: Probably you mean to get notified 'before' the browser really quits?

Comment: @Vincent Yup. Getting notified right before the browser quits is what I meant. Thank you for clearing it up:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Executing some JavaScript before the window is unloaded

You can hook the `OnBeforeUnload` event of the `window`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        if (iWantTo) {
            return "Don't leave me!";
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

## Using a heartbeat to know when the user has left

Or create a JavaScript timer that pings your sever every XX seconds.  When the pings stop, you can assume the user has closed the browser or navigated away.

http://ajaxpatterns.org/archive/Heartbeat.php

Comment: Oh, that is a creative method, but it won't work very well in my case as I am storing data on the client.

Comment: darn. ty though. i'll modify my stuff to work with your code :)

Answer (score 1):

They have lots of good stuff in their documentation. `onRemoved` of the window object would seem to do it.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#event-onRemoved

Or perhaps you mean tabs. In which case the `onRemoved` for the tab object would do it.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onRemoved

[API Index](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/)

Comment: I think these APIs are only available to extensions. OP is talking about a regular website I think.