# Detecting Chrome browser exit?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I tried everything but nothing seems to work for me. I tried to detect the closing of the browsing by detecting window closing like the code below but that does not work for me. What am I doing wrong and is there another solution to detect Chrome closing?

```
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(windowId){
  alert("Browser exit!");
});
```

Comment: Have you tryed this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961544/chrome-detect-when-browser-exits

Comment: I certainly did. Nothing works. I do have to mention if that wasn't obvious from the code that I am trying to detect that Chrome exits from an extension.

Answer (score 2):

Your general problem is that quitting the browser means that browser can no longer run your script to check if it has quit yet -- it's like trying to ask a person if they've died: the answer (if you get one) is only ever going to be "no".

One solution you might try is a long-running background page with the [`background` permission](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html#bg):

> Makes Chrome start up early and and shut down late, so that apps and extensions can have a longer life.
>
> When any installed hosted app, packaged app, or extension has "background" permission, Chrome runs (invisibly) as soon as the user logs into their computer—before the user launches Chrome. The "background" permission also makes Chrome continue running (even after its last window is closed) until the user explicitly quits Chrome.

This permission allows the Chrome to keep running your extension even after all browser windows have closed. Normally, Chrome can only do things when it has windows open, so we run into the problem of Chrome being unable to detect when all windows have closed (as explained above). With the background permission, Chrome retains the ability to run extension code even when all windows have closed.

Comment: What do you mean by "background permission"? Do you mean background persistence like so: "background": {"persistent": true, ...}

Comment: @user436390 Sorry, I used the wrong link! No, the permission is actually called "background" (see updated link), and it's different from persistence.

Comment: @user436390 Great, I'm glad it works! If your problem is solved, you should [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so the question is marked as resolved.

Comment: I don't think your argument that the question is paradoxical is a valid one. In any application, there's a moment 'just before exit' that enables the developer to signal events and do relevant stuff.
It's not like the action happens by itself all of a sudden (like a power outage), there's a button click involved e.g

Answer (score 0):

i'm just looking to get control when my extension exits not the entire browser; my extension uses a text box exclusively, so i set its onblur property to a function and put my exit code there; probably not what you're looking for, but it works for me!

the chrome developer website recommends not using background pages due to "memory and other resources they consume";

i agree a more consistent way to get control on extension exit would be useful; it is an html page that otherwise seems integrated with the dom;

Answer (score 0):

chrome does not provide any API to detect chrome browser is going close. However, we can detect chrome browser opening event inside background page when using chrome extension.

background.js

```
    chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function () {
        console.log("extension started: " + Date.now());
    });
```

this event will fire when chrome browser will start. next you can use any trick to identify the chrome browser was exit.