# Chrome Extension - Clear chrome sync storage on browser close

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, storage

As the title states, when the user closes the browser I need to clear all stored variables associated with the extension that are stored via:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'...
```

From here (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime) I have seen that you can clear local data on some events like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
 chrome.storage.local.clear()
})
```

The difference is I need to clear synced data on exit of the browser.

Comment: There's no event to detect when the browser is closing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting Chrome browser exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928105/detecting-chrome-browser-exit)

Comment: The closest solution is to register a separate [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) application, start it from the extension, and when it receives `-1`, have it do a manual clean up of the extension data directory in the browser profile.

Comment: The detecting chrome browser exit question addresses half of the question, detection, however even their proposed solution isn't working. I added it to a js file called startUp.js with these contents: chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function () {
        chrome.storage.local.clear()
});

Comment: Nothing seems to be happening.

Comment: Can you show the native messaging solution in a little more detail? Seems like a very broad approach.