# Detect when chrome browzer exit with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I consult this link, and I write code to detect when chrome browzer exit.
[Chrome - Detect When Browser Exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961544/chrome-detect-when-browser-exits)

I try to change ".bind" to ".on" ,but this don't work. Please advise.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "test",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "jquery.min.js",
      "test.js"
  ]}, 
    "permissions": [
      "background",
      "storage"
    ]
}
```

test.js

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    if (window.length === 1) { // when browzer exit
        return "Don't leave me!";
    } else {
        return "idle";
    }
});
```

Comment: have you console for errors??

Comment: No, I don't have error.

Comment: i think its onbeforeunload and not beforeunload..try it

Comment: I tried to change "onbeforeunload", but it doesn't work.